# Regex to replace word in comma separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using javascript .replace() to remove a word from a comma separated list of words and have a solution that works, but it is clumsy and I think there must be a better one.

regex looks like:

```
/,word1|word1,?/
```

The handles the cases of leading, embedded and trailing and removes the correct number of commas eg.

```
word1,word2,word3
word2,word1,word3
word2,word3,word1
All result in word2,word3
word1 on its own is removed completely
```

Is there a way to do it without that repeated word1 in the regex pattern?

Comment: If the regex you have works, why change it, it seems fine to me ?

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't think you can find better regex.

Answer (score 0):

There are no really better or shorter patterns to do that. All you can do is to avoid false positive by adding word boundaries where the comma may be missing:

```
,word1\b|\bword1\b,?
```

If you have to deal with a large string, and only if the first letter isn't too frequent, you can try to use the first character discrimination technic to reduce the number of positions where the pattern will be tested:

```
(?=[,w])(?:,word1\b|\bword1\b,?)
```

*(note that you need to test that in real life to see if it is really benefic.)*

**Other way without regex**

if your target string is only a comma separated list, using a split/join stay the best solution.